# SharePoint view limitation

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library in SharePoint online. I keep on dumping the records into it. As SharePoint have a 5000 record view limitation the moment it reaches that limit, still I will be able to upload documents but it doesn't show up any where.

Eventually I end up creating a new  view and apply a filter and then the document starts showing up under the new view.

My question here is: Is there a way to automatically create a view when it reaches the 5000 limitation and put the newly uploaded documents to the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this via MS Flow/Workflow & server side apps/scripts of course but it's not a good approach to the issue IMO.

Have you indexed the columns? I just tested this now on a document library with 20k documents and I'm able to filter. There are limitations which you should look into (complex filtering), that's where compound indexes come in.

If you still have issues then I recommend you give the highlighted content web-part a try. You can create custom search queries & it looks similar to a document library if u set the settings correctly. The only meh thing about this approach is there is a delay for search to update, from 15 mins to 6 hours depending on how much data you have

Comment: Can you please provide me a example of creating   the view using MS Flow/Workflow & server side apps/scripts